# Hiding keyboard in HoneyComb application

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, soft-keyboard

I am developing application for Android HoneyComb.
In it I don't want to show system keyboard when I try to focus on `EditText` 
as I have my own virtual keyboard. Even I tried as `edittext.setInputType(0);`
and in XML file `android:inputtype="none"` but both doesn't work.
So please help me to find solution for it.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the edittexts OnFocusListener put:

```
        getWindow()
            .setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

(I have not yet tried this, as I'm not currently at a computer with the Android SDK.)

I think what you want to do is use the [`InputMethodManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html) to disable the input method (IME) from appearing.  The following line of code is an example of getting a reference to the `InputMethodManager`.

```
InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

Then use one of the `InputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow()` methods, with the window token of the appropriate view and with the appropriate flag(s), to ensure the IME does not appear.

Comment: & @ninjasense----Thanks for reply...It working now as I just make Editext editable=false.